# result of ApplyLinearImpulse is different with the first one - Box2D

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

i'm making a breakout game with cocos2d-x 3.x and box2d, referencing http://www.raywenderlich.com/

my game logic is this.

1. at init, call StartGame function. in here i use ApplyLinearImpulse to move ball.
2. if ball hits the bottom wall, ball stops moving.
3. click screen then call StartGame function, transforming ball's position and ApplyLinearImpulse again.
4. repeat number 2 and 3

the problem is ball's speed at number 1 is different with the result of others even if i gave same force. at beginning ball's speed is slow but after one loop, ball's speed is very fast.
 i dont't know why... i need help.
here is my source code.

```
#include "GameScene.h"


#define PTM_RATIO 32

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* GameScene::createScene() {

    Scene* scene = Scene::create();
    Layer* layer = GameScene::create();

    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool GameScene::init() {

    if(!Layer::init()){
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    // Create a world
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    _world = new b2World(gravity);

    // create contact listener
    _contactListener = new MyContactListener();
    _world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);

    CreateWall(visibleSize);
    CreateBall();
    CreatePaddle(visibleSize);

    label = LabelTTF::create("Game Over", "Arial", 32);
    label->setColor(Color3B(255,255,255));
    label->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2));
    this->addChild(label);

    b2PrismaticJointDef jointDef;
    b2Vec2 worldAxis(1.0f, 0.0f);
    jointDef.collideConnected = true;
    jointDef.Initialize(_paddleBody, _groundBody, _paddleBody->GetWorldCenter(), worldAxis);
    _world->CreateJoint(&jointDef);



    // add touch events
    auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
    _touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    _touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchBegan, this);
    _touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchMoved, this);
    _touchListener->onTouchCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchCancelled, this);
    _touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchEnded, this);
    dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(_touchListener, this);

    Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(GameScene::tick), this, 1/60, false);

    StartGame(0);

    return true;
}

void GameScene::tick(float dt) {
    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    if(!gameOver) {

        for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {
            if(b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
                Sprite *s = static_cast<Sprite*>(b->GetUserData());
                if(s->getTag() == 1) {
                    b2Vec2 velocity =  b->GetLinearVelocity();
                    float32 speed = velocity.Length();
                    if(speed > maxSpeed)
                        b->SetLinearDamping(0.5f);
                    else if(speed < maxSpeed)
                        b->SetLinearDamping(0.0f);
                }
                s->setPosition(Point(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO));
                s->setRotation(-1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle()));
            }
        }
        for_each(_contactListener->_contacts.begin(), _contactListener->_contacts.end(),
                 [&](MyContact contact) {
                     if(contact.contain(_bottomFixture, _ballFixture)) {
                         cocos2d::log("Ball hit Bottom");
                         GameOver();
                     }
                 } );
    }
}

bool GameScene::onTouchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *event){
    if(gameOver) {
        StartGame(1);
        return true;
    }

    if(_mouseJoint != NULL) return true;
    cocos2d::log("touch began test");
    Point location = touch->getLocation();
    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

    if(_paddleFixture->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {
        b2MouseJointDef md;
        md.bodyA = _groundBody;
        md.bodyB = _paddleBody;
        md.target = locationWorld;
        md.collideConnected = true;
        md.maxForce = 1000.0f * _paddleBody->GetMass();

        _mouseJoint = static_cast<b2MouseJoint*>(_world->CreateJoint(&md));
        _paddleBody->SetAwake(true);
    }

    return true;
}

void GameScene::onTouchMoved(Touch *touch, Event *event) {

    if(_mouseJoint == NULL) return;

    Point location = touch->getLocation();
    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

    _mouseJoint->SetTarget(locationWorld);
}

void GameScene::onTouchCancelled(Touch *touch, Event *event) {

    if(_mouseJoint) {
        _world->DestroyJoint(_mouseJoint);
        _mouseJoint = NULL;
    }
}

void GameScene::onTouchEnded(Touch *touch, Event *event) {
    if(_mouseJoint) {
        _world->DestroyJoint(_mouseJoint);
        _mouseJoint = NULL;
    }
}

void GameScene::CreateWall(Size visibleSize) {
    // Create edges around the entire class
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0, 0);
    _groundBody = _world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);

    b2EdgeShape groundBox;
    b2FixtureDef groundBoxDef;
    groundBoxDef.shape = &groundBox;

    groundBox.Set(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(visibleSize.width/PTM_RATIO,0));
    _bottomFixture  = _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);

    groundBox.Set(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0,visibleSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);

    groundBox.Set(b2Vec2(0,visibleSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(visibleSize.width/PTM_RATIO,visibleSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);

    groundBox.Set(b2Vec2(visibleSize.width/PTM_RATIO,visibleSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(visibleSize.width/PTM_RATIO,0));
    _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);

}

void GameScene::CreateBall() {

    // create ball texture
    ball = Sprite::create("ball.png");
    ball->setPosition(Point(100,100));
    ball->setTag(1);
    this->addChild(ball);

    // create ball body
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(100/PTM_RATIO, 100/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.angle = 0;
    ballBodyDef.userData = ball;
    ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

    // create circle shape
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = 26.0/PTM_RATIO;

    //create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    ballShapeDef.friction = 0.0f;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = 1.0f;
    _ballFixture = ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
}

void GameScene::CreatePaddle(Size visibleSize) {
    //create paddle
    userPaddle = Sprite::create("paddle.png");
    userPaddle->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2, 50));
    this->addChild(userPaddle);

    // create paddle body
    b2BodyDef paddleBodyDef;
    paddleBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    paddleBodyDef.position.Set(visibleSize.width/2/PTM_RATIO, 50/PTM_RATIO);
    paddleBodyDef.userData = userPaddle;
    _paddleBody = _world->CreateBody(&paddleBodyDef);

    // create paddle shape
    b2PolygonShape paddleShape;
    paddleShape.SetAsBox(userPaddle->getContentSize().width/2/PTM_RATIO, userPaddle->getContentSize().height/2/PTM_RATIO);

    // create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef paddleShapeDef;
    paddleShapeDef.shape = &paddleShape;
    paddleShapeDef.density = 10.0f;
    paddleShapeDef.friction = 0.4f;
    paddleShapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
    _paddleFixture = _paddleBody->CreateFixture(&paddleShapeDef);

}

void GameScene::GameOver() {

    gameOver = true;
    _world->ClearForces();
    ballBody->SetAngularVelocity(0);
    ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0,0));
    ballBody->SetLinearDamping(0);
    label->setVisible(true);

}

void GameScene::StartGame(int stage) {

    ballBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(100/PTM_RATIO, 100/PTM_RATIO), 0);
    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(150,150);
    //ballBody->ApplyForceToCenter(force);
    ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
    gameOver = false;
    label->setVisible(false);
}

GameScene::~GameScene() {
    delete _world;
    delete _contactListener;
    _groundBody = NULL;
}
```

Comment: may this is due to that body is in motion and you apply force then it accelerate it.

Comment: @Singhak do you mean that the body already has  velocity then i accelerate it? i don't think so. because i set ball's velocity to 0 when it hits the bottom. and world's step function is still called in tick.

Comment: How about setting the velocity to zero in StartGame instead of GameOver... since that's where you actually need it. Even if you set it to zero in GameOver, the step function is still called so the ball may get some velocity after that by from reacting to the collision (although if this was the case, you should be able to see it in the debug draw easily). You could also just not do the world step if gameOver is true.

Comment: I am also facing same issue ... how can we apply constant Impulse force on body !!!    See my question ::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887940/why-applylinearimpulse-is-not-same-every-time-on-same-body-with-same-values-usin