# why ApplyLinearImpulse is not same every time on same body with same values using box2d in cocos2d - x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I want to know the exact functioning of Impulse Function in box2d. right now i am trying to apply Impulse on same kind of bodies with same kind of value of force .

For Ex.

```
b2Vec2 force =  b2Vec2(20,50);
MyBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, MyBody->GetPosition(), true);
```

on above example i am applying force with static values on my dynamic bodies , now every Mybody not behaving same kind of force. why is it so ?!!

According to my understanding , it should behave same every time. or am i wrong ?!..  please help me to understand. Thank you.